# 502 - Bad Gateway when trying to register a user via Passport JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, passport-local

So I'm building a local registration and authentication system, using Passport Local.
I thought the registration works because this shows up in the terminal:

```
Mongoose: users.findOne({ username: 'user6' }, { fields: undefined })
User already exists with username: user6
message User Already Exists
Mongoose: users.findOne({ username: 'user7' }, { fields: undefined })
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
Mongoose: users.insert({ info: 'hujk,trfyulryflrfyuk,yhj', name: 'User Seven', email: 'user7@gmail.com', password: '$2a$10$d1fCoF7r3lRsyzbAzZlw0e74rqPhXLL7LatQaNSIi4UIVtPhXRGH.', username: 'user7', _id: ObjectId("59567dd1004be60ca0bf44a2"), isAdmin: false, __v: 0 })
User Registration succesful
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("59567dd1004be60ca0bf44a2") }, { fields: undefined })
```

The problem is that it this registration ends up getting 502 - Bad Gateway error instead of the homepage. Also, when I go to MongoDB and search for all the users, user6 and user7 do not appear. I checked and the url remained.
This is the local registration code:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, username, password, email, name, info, done) {

        function findOrCreateUser(){
            // find a user in Mongo with provided username
            User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
                // In case of any error, return using the done method
                if (err){
                    console.log('Error in SignUp: '+err);
                    return done(err);
                }
                // already exists
                if (user) {
                    console.log('User already exists with username: '+username);
                    return done(null, false, console.log('message','User Already Exists'));
                } else {
                    // if there is no user with that email
                    // create the user
                    var newUser = new User();

                    // set the user's local credentials
                    newUser.username = username;
                    newUser.password = createHash(password);
                    newUser.email = email;
                    newUser.name = name;
                    newUser.info = info;
                    // save the user
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err){
                            console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);  
                            throw err;  
                        }
                        console.log('User Registration succesful');    
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        // Delay the execution of findOrCreateUser and execute the method
        // in the next tick of the event loop
        process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
    }));
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I can't really find it anywhere.

Comment: Are any of the console.log commands inside your findOrCreateUser(..) showing up in your console?

Comment: Are you using `passport-local`? If so, where are the `email`, `name` and `info` arguments coming from? I thought that the verification callback accepted at most 4 arguments (`req`, which is optional, and `username`, `password` and `done`).

Comment: To add onto @robertklep 's comment, look at line 88 and 90 https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js

It only have two options for callbacks.

Comment: @robertklep Since I need more data for my users, I added in the strategy file... I saw these alterations are optional in several places.

Comment: @RohitSaxena They do. That's what I don't get.

Comment: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/27306373-typeerror-done-is-not-a-function This is where I've seen these alterations. I can't seem to find another way to add these  variables to the User model.

Comment: @ValS On that link look at kire73's message that starts with "This happened when adding a param to my Strategy in my passport.js file:"

Did you also modify your strategy file?

Comment: @ValS you shouldn't edit files in `node_modules/`. Instead, I would assume that all that additional information is accessible through `req` in some form or another (`req.body`, most likely).

Comment: @robertklep It is, but the problem is it simply won't "stick" to the user model, since it's predefined to only username and password.

Comment: @ValS that sounds like you should expand your User model to contain those new fields?

Comment: @ValS you can add information into the req and then pull it. So you  can do req.user.email = ... and then read it in your strategy.

Comment: @robertklep I did... it didn't work and that's why I added those fields to the strategy file to begin with.

Comment: @ValS a 502 should have been accompanied by a (Node) server error, you should try and find out what's the error causing your Node server to crash.